# Necesito ayuda en concrete5

Tags: phpmyadmin, aplicación-web

tengo un error en la pagina en la cual estoy trabajando y me sale este error
¿Alguien sabe como resolverlo este error viene del CMS - concrete5?
 Fatal error:  Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved in /mnt/target04/877373/www.lamacchinaitaliana.com/web/content/updates/concrete5.6.3.1_updater/concrete/libraries/object.php on line 3

Comment: Estás declarando una clase con el nombre `Object`, lo cual no se puede por ser una palabra reservada. El mensaje de error es claro.

Comment: Es muy cierto lo que comenta @A.Cedano, te dejo una pagina web donde describe las palabras reservadas donde no puedes declararla como una funcion, clase o variables. https://byspel.com/palabras-reservadas-php/